# Multiple fullscreen background images on vertical site

Tags: jquery, css, background, fullscreen

Using the JQuery ScrollTo plugin, I've created the following vertical site [LINK](http://www.thenally.com/wordpress/).  The basic page architecture is as follows:

```
<div id="fixed-menu">
     <!-- MAIN MENU FIXED TO TOP OF WINDOW -->
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="mask">
          <div id="page1">
             <!-- PAGE 1 CONTENT -->
          </div>
          <div id="page2">
             <!-- PAGE 2 CONTENT -->
          </div>
          <div id="page3">
             <!-- PAGE 3 CONTENT -->
          </div>
          <div id="page4">
             <!-- PAGE 4 CONTENT -->
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My issue is when trying to have a fullscreen background image for each separate 'page'.  I have experience using the JQuery plugin Fullscreenr to create a background image which properly adapts to different screen resolutions, etc.  I am unfamiliar, though, with how to set a different one for each 'page' of the site.  I've been thinking that an alternative may be to trigger a change of background image depending on which menu item is selected.  Does anyone have any experience or advice in the matter?  I have tried stacking the images, but I want to avoid seeing partial background images at any point on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a hard time getting JQuery Waypoints to work successfully, I ended up simply changing the background image after a mouse-click of the relevant heading.  Because the site is only auto-scrolling (no mouse-wheel functionality), this will work fine.

The JQuery code used is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.panel-about').click(function(){
    $("#bgimg").attr('src',"<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/bg2.jpg");
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

So when the link with class 'panel-about' is clicked, the background image changes to bg2.jpg from the existing bg1.jpg specified in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Jquery waypoints.  Basically this lets you execute a javascript event when the site scrolls to a certain point.  http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

So you would set a way point where each of your "pages" appears in the page and change the background image accordingly.

Comment: hey thats great. thanks for your help.  I'll repost when I get some jquery written...I'm pretty novice with it.

Comment: I've made a dismal attempt at trying to replace the current #bgimg with a new one...I can bring animation into it later.  Maybe you can spot why it's not working, I don't know if I understand the syntax. `<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $('#item2').waypoint(function() {
  $("#bgimg").replaceWith( "<img id="bgimg" src="http://www.thenally.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Nally Theme 0200/images/bg2.jpg" />" );
 });
</script>`